# Remote Web Deploy not working

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have developed several ASP.NET 4.5 applications and I want to publish them to a remote computer running IIS 8, using Web Deploy.

I created two sites in IIS8, Site1 and Site2. I created a single IIS User and I gave permission to access both sites to this user.

I can publish the first site via Web Deploy, but I cannot publish the second site.

When I try to publish the second site, I get this error in Visual Studio

```
2>Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to     https://27.147.144.98:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=NSU ...
2>Adding ACL's for path (NSU)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4255,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. ((6/30/2015 12:36:37 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
2>
2>(6/30/2015 12:36:37 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
2>The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
2>Publish failed to deploy.
```

**The first site is published correctly always. The problems occurs only for the second site.**

Comment: check the app pool, and test the connections using impersonated user, also i would recommend checking the web deploy credentials ,
can you please share Web Deploy error log from Event Viewer ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error but also had Fiddler2 running which seemed like it was interfering with the deployment. When I closed it, things worked again. Make sure you test the connection beforehand.